# Upload image to WEB API, Xamarin.Forms with Media Plugin

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a simple WEB API project to upload image to Microsoft Azure, everything is working fine when I test it with Postman. What I'm trying to do next is to upload the image in Xamarin.Forms Andorid project. I followed the Documentation abailable here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin and I already created all the necessary files. I have two buttons with onClick events, those two mian functions are responsible for taking&saving and uploading the image :

```
  public partial class AddOgloszeniePage : ContentPage
    {
        public MediaFile file;
        public AddOgloszeniePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void TapOpenCamera_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
                return;
            }

             file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg"
            });

            if (file == null)
                return;

            await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

            ImgOgloszenie.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                return stream;
            });
        }
```

and

```
        private async void BntSubmit_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var imageArray =  FilesHelper.ReadFully(file.GetStream());
            file.Dispose();
            var wojewodztwo = PickerWojewodztwo.Items[PickerWojewodztwo.SelectedIndex];
            var kategoria = PickerKategoria.Items[PickerKategoria.SelectedIndex];

            
            var ogloszeniaUser = new OgloszeniaUser()
            {
                UserName = EntName.Text,
                Phone = EntPhone.Text,
                Email = EntEmail.Text,
                Item = EntItem.Text,
                Wojewodztwo = wojewodztwo,
                Category = kategoria,
                ImageArray = imageArray,
            };
            ApiServices apiServices = new ApiServices();
            var response = await apiServices.AddItem(ogloszeniaUser);
            if (!response)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("error", "can not add picture", "close");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("success", "picture added", "close");
            }
        }
```

I'm able to take take the picture but I'm unbale to upload it in Xamarin.Forms project despite the fact that I can POST it in Postman. Im getting error: **System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.'**. I think there is something wrong with the **stream**, but I dont know what exacly is the issue? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.objectdisposedexception?view=net-5.0

Comment: my guess would be that `file.Dispose();` is the culprit, but if you look at the stack trace of the exception it will tell you **exactly which line** causes the exception

Comment: Does the problem persist after removing `file.Dispose();` ?

Comment: After removing file.Dispose(); I'm not getting error but I'm still unable to upload the image, !response condition showing Display alert "can not add picture", maybe it could not access the stream from the second function...

Comment: then you need to debug inside `apiServices.AddItem` to determine what is going wrong